# Encrypt and Decrypt Fields in Database With Larave Spatie Package CipherSweet

Tags: laravel, security, encryption

I am using Spatie package spatie/laravel-ciphersweet. I can encrypt the fields in the database by using this package.

But I can not decrypt the fields when I required to show in the frontend. This is model Class Where I am describing which fields to encrypt. This is working fine.

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements CipherSweetEncrypted
    { 
    use UsesCipherSweet;
    ..
    public static function configureCipherSweet(EncryptedRow $encryptedRow): void
    {
        $encryptedRow
            ->addField('email')
            ->addBlindIndex('email', new BlindIndex('email_index'));
    }
    ..
    }
```

I have 2 Questions Now:

1. How to perform Blind Search
2. How to Decrypt Field to show on frontend

For Blind Search I am using code like this:

```
$user = User::whereBlind('email', 'email_index', $request->email)->first();
dd($user);
```

This is giving error:

SodiumException : Not using the native libsodium bindings

For Decrypt Fields I can not figure-out how to decrypt fields to show the email on frontend.

For Blind Search I tried this code

```
$user = User::whereBlind('email', 'email_index', $request->email)->first();
dd($user);
```

But this is giving error message : SodiumException : Not using the native libsodium bindings

Another thing i can not figure-out is to decrypt the encrypted field so that i can show on frontend.

Comment: are you using a php version older than 7.2? otherwise you should have sodium already inlcuded

Comment: I am using PHP version 8.1.26